# Dvd write fails on windows 7 works great on windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, dvd, dvd-burning

When I try to burn a disc on windows 7 ultimate, I get a calibration error. However dvd burns fine when I boot into windows XP (same machine)! Little guidance please :)

Comment: Which CD/DVD burning software are you using?  Is it up-to-date and fully Win7 compatible?  Did it ever work under Windows 7?  Have you tried updating your optical drive's firmware?

Comment: I have tried lots of softwares, windows 7 built in burn, imgBurn, cdBurnerXP..none of them works. I dont think it ever worked in windows 7. If its a firmware issue then it shouldnt be working even in XP..right?